# How to set default parameter as class object in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to set my function with class object parameter set as default. But when I try to do that it fails in compilation.

```
class base {
 // ...
};

int myfunc(int a, base b = NULL) {
    if (NULL = b) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    } else {
    // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Here when i am trying to compile it, this gives me error that "Default Argument base b have int type"

Comment: You need to make `b` a pointer to `base` for this to work: `base* b = NULL`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have three obvious options here.

First, use overloads so the caller can choose to pass `b` or not.

```
int myfunc(int a) { ... }
int myfunc(int a, base& b) { ... }
```

This way you can pass `b` without having to use a pointer. Note that you should make `b` a reference or pointer type to avoid [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the object.

Secondly, if you don't want 2 separate implementations, make `b` a pointer, which can be set to `NULL`.

```
int myfunc(int a, base* b = NULL) { ... }
```

Third, you could use something to encapsulate the concept of nullable, such as [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

```
int myfunc(int a, boost::optional<base&> b = boost::optional<base&>()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 28):

Objects can't be `NULL` in C++.

To set the parameter to default, just use:

```
int myfunc(int a, base b = base())
```

Comment: Is `base()` calling `base`'s constructor?

Comment: @David yes, `base()` default-constructs an object of type `base`.

Comment: In this case how would one check if an argument was supplied since `base` can't be compared to `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

[@tenfour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402169/) answer forgot to mention another possible way. You also define a global variable object which you can construct as you like, then set it as the default value:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyCustomClassType
{
  int var;

  friend std::ostream &operator<<( 
        std::ostream &output, const MyCustomClassType &my_custom_class_type )
  {
    output << my_custom_class_type.var;
    return output;
  }
};

// C++11 syntax initialization call to the default constructor
MyCustomClassType _my_custom_class_type{};

void function(MyCustomClassType my_custom_class_type = _my_custom_class_type) {
  std::cout << my_custom_class_type << std::endl;
}

/**
 * To build it use:
 *     g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
 */
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  function();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A hack or ugly solution would be do a static cast from null:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyCustomClassType {
  int var;

  friend std::ostream &operator<<( 
         std::ostream &output, const MyCustomClassType &my_custom_class_type )
  {
    output << my_custom_class_type.var;
    return output;
  }
};

void function(
       MyCustomClassType my_custom_class_type = *static_cast<MyCustomClassType*>( nullptr )
    ) 
{
  std::cout << my_custom_class_type << std::endl;
}

/**
 * To build it use:
 *     g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
 */
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  function();
}
```

But, running this gives you directly a segmentation fault due dereferencing a null pointer. I am not sure when this would be useful.